# My Android Studio Layout is initializing without ending

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout, initialization

My Android Studio does not initialize the design view of the layout. It appears "initializing" and then nothing happens. What's to be done? I attached here a screenshot.
The screenshot:

[image]